# is it possible to delete wml variable

Tags: php, wml

unfortunately, I am using old technologies to build wap mobile app with WML, which is suitable for old mobiles (over 10 years old).

we can create a variable in wml with

```
<setvar name="varName" value="123" />
```

we can reset the variable value, or change it's value in the same way.
but how to delete the variable it self? is it possible?

thank you in advanced.

note: I use openwave simulator with XML editor for WML Development .

Comment: What are you doing that doesn't work if you just clear the variable as in `<setvar name='varName' value=''/>`?

Comment: @kainaw thanks for replying, I known that as i mentioned in my question above, what I don't know: is there any way to delete the variable itself?